# Can't put anything over particles.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, particles.js

So I'm working on my site, and I want to incorporate the cool line particle from the particles.js library. I have the particles working and such it all works fine. When I try to put my text onto it, it forces it below all the particles. I don't know why this is happening. I've tried putting it above, below and inside of the  tags, but it all ways ends up above or below the particles, or no where at all.

Here is my code:

```css
/* =============================================================================
   HTML5 CSS Reset Minified - Eric Meyer
   ========================================================================== */

html,body,div,span,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,abbr,address,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,samp,small,strong,sub,sup,var,b,i,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;outline:0;font-size:100%;vertical-align:baseline;background:transparent}
body{line-height:1}
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block}
nav ul{list-style:none}
blockquote,q{quotes:none}
blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after{content:none}
a{margin:0;padding:0;font-size:100%;vertical-align:baseline;background:transparent;text-decoration:none}
mark{background-color:#ff9;color:#000;font-style:italic;font-weight:bold}
del{text-decoration:line-through}
abbr[title],dfn[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted;cursor:help}
table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}
hr{display:block;height:1px;border:0;border-top:1px solid #ccc;margin:1em 0;padding:0}
input,select{vertical-align:middle}
li{list-style:none}


/* =============================================================================
   My CSS
   ========================================================================== */

/* ---- base ---- */

html,body{ 
 background:#111;
}

html{
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

body{
  font:normal 75% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

canvas{
  display:block;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}


/* ---- stats.js ---- */

.count-particles{
  background: #000022;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 80px;
  color: #13E8E9;
  font-size: .8em;
  text-align: left;
  text-indent: 4px;
  line-height: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.js-count-particles{
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

#stats,
.count-particles{
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#stats{
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.count-particles{
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}


/* ---- particles.js container ---- */

#particles-js{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: darkcyan;
}
#particles canvas{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 999;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- DO NOT TOUCH -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>C#Web - Professional Web Development</title>
  <meta name="description" content="C#Web is a web development & graphic design shop run by Gosintary and Lorsharish. They charge low prices and provide very high quality work!">
  <meta name="author" content="Ethan Pszanowski" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/style.css">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
    <link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Plugin CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/freelancer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- END OF DO NOT TOUCH -->
<!-- START OF CSS -->
    <style>
        .header{
            height: 650px;
            width: 100%;
            font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
            color: white;
            margin-top: 104px;
        }
        .header p{
            
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-secondary fixed-top text-uppercase" id="mainNav">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">C# WEB</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right text-uppercase bg-primary text-white rounded" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          Menu
          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
              <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
              <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#ethan">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
              <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Header -->
        <div class="layer">
            <div id="particles-js"></div>
        </div>
    <div class="header">
        <h1>123</h1>
    </div>

<!-- DO NOT TOUCH -->
<!-- scripts -->
<script src="particles.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<!-- END OF DO NOT TOUCH -->

</body>
</html>
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding a `z-index: 0;` to the layer class, and a `z-index: 100;` to anything you want to put on top of the layer div. Sorry, just saw you already have that in the CSS. You want particles to have a lower z-index than whatever you put over it basically.

Comment: @CodinMoldovanu, this fixed the background issue, now the particles display over the background. However when I did this my text vanished. I tried also setting their z-index:100; to everything else.

Comment: EDIT: Turns out my text is still being forced down. I tried further increasing the z-index, but that didn't fix it. I tried placing the text inside the particles div, nothing. The background is now fixed though.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is long overdue, but I was having the same issue and added
"position: relative;"

to the  containing my content (e.g. the  element I wanted to display over the particles background ).

This worked for me! Hope someone else might find this solution useful.